# Android, Animation in progress bar doesn't run

Tags: android, animation, custom-controls, progress-bar, custom-action

In my application I want to override default look and feel of progress bar. Default one is a rectangle and has loading animation. So, what i did?

First in res/drawable i created loadinganim.xml (loading01-6 are my .png images).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  

<animation-list 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:oneshot="false" >  

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading01" android:duration="300" />  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading02" android:duration="300" />  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading03" android:duration="300" />  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading04" android:duration="300" />  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading05" android:duration="300" />  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading06" android:duration="300" /> 

</animation-list>
```

Then in res\layout, i created another xml file, named layout_loading.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ImageView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/blankImageView"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:src="@drawable/loading01"/>
```

In code, I have a button that when you press it progress bar will appear. The code is:

```
private ProgressDialog progressBar;
private AnimationDrawable myAnimation;

Button btnCustom1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.custom1);
        btnCustom1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "");
                progressBar.setContentView(R.layout.layout_loading);
                progressBar.setCancelable(true);
                final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) progressBar.findViewById(R.id.blankImageView); 
                imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loadinganim);
                myAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
                myAnimation.start(); 
            }
        });
```

The problem is when i click on the button, the image will show but there is no animation. like following image. Please tell me how can i run the animation? or where is my fault?

Thank you for helping me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

Actually the above code doesn't have problem and its correct. The reason of not showing of animation is because of a bug (at least, i think) in Android 2.3.3 (API 10). When I run the project on other emulator (API 15), it was animating fine and it has not any problem.

Therefore, **hey Google guy**, please do something this is a real bug.